# JavaScript to jQuery for KendoUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been using KendoUI and have been using they're command functions. However to call JS I must call named jS functions. No huge deal. When I use the "This" key word it brings back the entire grid and I mus find a value of a child from a sibling of the same parent elements and i wound up doing this ugly thing. The question I have is how can I turn this "thing" into something jqueryable readable and comprehensible

```
function AddRole(e) {
  var $ParentNode = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].children[0].getAttribute("value", 0);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a job for [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Could you post the HTML structure that you are dealing with?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the element structure -- `$( e.target ).parent().parent().children().eq(1).children().first().val()` isn't much prettier.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/siqniz/MTMCk/2/

Comment: @KaiCriticallyAcclaimedCooper: Use `$(e.target)`. Could you update the fiddle with the relevant HTML parts?

Comment: Without the HTML it cannot really be improved, because all we know is that you want to traverse up two levels and then traverse down, which is what your code already does. If you post a sample of your HTML then it's possible to give a neater solution.

Comment: My fiddle has been updated as close as I reasonably think it can. Telerik applies all sorts or random style. Thanks every one

Comment: You need to post a link to the updated fiddle. The link above still points to the one with no HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you have other problems.

If you rely on such a structure `e.target.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].children[0]`, your Markup and JS do not scale at all.

Use the oppurtunity to create scalable and consistent code. Or at least, set some id, class or html5 data attribute on the `children[0]` element in order to identify it properly.

Comment: Sorry I thought I was saved it the first time: http://jsfiddle.net/siqniz/MTMCk/7/